# Installing VirtualBox 4.0.8 on Windows 7 hangs

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, virtualbox

I already have a previous version of VirtualBox 4.0.4 on my computer and I want to make an upgrade by a direct "overwritten-installation".

But every time I try to do so, the installation get stuck when it comes to the "virtual ethernet card installation" stage. It says it would only take a while but actually never ends. Can anyone give advice?

Answer (score 4):

You might try uninstalling VirtualBox, ensure that "virtual ethernet card" and its driver are deleted, then install the new version.

Search for the "virtual ethernet card" and its driver in Device Manager before you start. If you have any doubts, add the info to your post.

Comment: Thanks!  I couldn't uninstall virtualbox since the crashed installation attempt hade stopped in such a fashion that it wasn't listed as installed.  But disabling those network connections then installing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @harrymc's hints. It seems the issue is caused by the **connection sharing** between my real ethernet adapter and VirtualBox's "host-only" ethernet adapter, which is once setup before. Here is my solution.

I opened the device manager with "Show hidden devices" checked. Surprisingly, I found "VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver" still existed even if I had no VirtualBox on my machine. I disabled all of them, then my connection lost immediately. Then I installed VirtualBox again and this time I met no obstacles. But I soon found that the internet connection was still blocked. I checked Network Center, only to see VirtualBox's card was working. So I uninstalled VirtualBox and had it installed for the third time, after which all runs perfectly.